# Binding UIButton tap gesture in UITableViewCell to observable in viewModel

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

What is the best way to handle tap gesture of `UIButton` in `UITableViewCell` when working with `RxSwift` and MVVM pattern? Should I bind it to a variable in `viewModel`?

Comment: Since the button is i suppose 4? classes away from the viewController, i would suggest using NotificationCenter.default.addObserver in the viewController and NotificationCenter.default.post that will be called on a button click inside the cell class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could provide a tap observable in your cell and bind it from the vc.

```
class SomeCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var detailsButton : UIButton!


    var detailsTap : Observable<Void>{

        return self.detailsButton.rx.tap.asObservable()

    }
}
```

Then in the vc:

```
private func bindTable(){
    //Bind the table elements
    elements.bind(to: self.table.rx.items) { [unowned self] (table, row, someModel) in
        let cell = cellProvider.cell(for: table, at: row) //Dequeue the cell here (do it your own way)

        //Subscribe to the tap using the proper disposeBag
        cell.detailsTap
            .subscribe(onNext:{ print("cell details button tapped")})
            .disposed(by: cell.disposeBag) //Notice it's using the cell's disposableBag and not self.disposeBag

        return cell
    }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    //Regular cell selection    
    self.table.rx
           .modelSelected(SomeModel.self)
           .subscribe(onNext:{ model in print("model")})
           .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

}
```

Comment: you can only access the button's info and the tap's info? can I get other var from SomeCell upon tap? Example a custom object's ID in the tableviewcell